# Aurelia parameterized routing outside navbar

Tags: aurelia

I have a navbar with the router links like in the Aurelia skeleton, but I want to also have parameterized links inside the router-view that change the router-view. Is this possible? If so, how do I access the router which is on App.ts? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to inject the router in your view-model. Like this:

```
import { autoinject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { Router } from 'aurelia-router';

@autoinject
export class MyScreenInRouterView {

   constructor(router: Router) {
      this.router = router;
   }
}
```

To use it in your view:

```
<a route-href="route: routeName; params.bind: { id: user.id }">${user.name}</a>
```

To generate URLs in code:

```
this.url = this.router.generate('routeName', { id: 123 });
```

To navigate to a route:

```
this.router.navigateToRoute('routeName', { id: 123 });
```

More information at http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/7

Comment: The problem with the 'To use it in your view' that you linked, both yours and in the Aurelia docs, is that it does not work for me. I am using this:

<a route-href="route: work-page/:work.id; params.bind: { id: ${work.id} }"></a>

But I get the error:

rror: A route with name 'undefined' could not be found. Check that `name: 'undefined'` was specified in the route's config

However, if I do a <p>${work.id}</p>, I can see the id correctly. It is only when binding it to the route-href that I get the error. If you know how to solve this, it would be of great help.

Comment: you don't have to declare the parameter part of the route name. For example: `<a route-href="route: work-page; params.bind: work.id"></a>`. Also, you should bind the variable without interpolation (${})

Comment: Ok, this works perfectly now, thanks for all the help!